# How can I add the device names that were not scanned (offline etc) by a PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell

Very very much a PowerShell newbie here I wanted a script to scan devices on the network and report on Local Admins. Found one out there and made some minor modifications to meet my needs - but I have one mod I cant work out how to do. Hoping someone out there will know a simple way to do it ?

The scrip below will read in a list of device names - scan them and output a dated report for all devices that are live and on-line. If the device is not accessible I get the following error on screen but nothing in the report.

I would like when it encounters an error that it writes to the report file - something along the lines of "$computor was not accessible!"

The code I am using is

```
$date = Get-Date -Format o | foreach {$_ -replace ":", "."}
ECHO "Starting scan"

$Result = @()

foreach($server in (gc .\servers.txt)){

$computer = [ADSI](”WinNT://” + $server + “,computer”)
$Group = $computer.psbase.children.find(”Administrators”)
$Filename = "c:\" + "LocalAdminAudit" + $date + ".txt"

function getAdmins
{
ECHO "SEARCHING FOR DEVICE"
$members = ($Group.psbase.invoke(”Members”) | %
{$_.GetType().InvokeMember(”Adspath”, ‘GetProperty’, $null, $_, $null)}) -
replace ('WinNT://DOMAIN/' + $server + '/'), '' -replace ('WinNT://DOMAIN/', 
'DOMAIN\') -replace ('WinNT://', '')
$members}
ECHO "READY TO WRITE OUTPUT"
$Result += Write-Output "SERVER: $server"
$Result += Write-Output ' '
$Result += ( getAdmins )
$Result += Write-Output '____________________________'
$Result += Write-Output ' '

ECHO "Record written"
}
# Added date run to report 
$result += Write-Output "Date Reported: $date"
$Result > $Filename
Invoke-Item $Filename

# replace "DOMAIN" with the domain name.



ECHO "Scan Complete"
```

And the on screen error when a machine is off line or otherwise doesn't respond is

Exception calling "Find" with "1" argument(s): "The network path was not found.
"
At \server\users\User.Name\Powershell Scripts\Get-Local-AdminsV3.ps1:1
0 char:40
+ $Group = $computer.psbase.children.find <<<< (”Administrators”)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

I would like when it encounters an error that it writes to the report file - something along the lines of "$computor was not accessible!" - I am pretty sure there must be an easy way of doing this - but I cant work it out so any tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You would need to use a try catch block to react to that error. Then, in the `catch`, you could add the appropriate error action.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt, mentioned in the comments. You can use a `Try`/`Catch` block inside your function to catch the error.

I also made some other changes. The most major is that I changed the function to contain all of the code necessary to get the local administrator group. Then the loop just calls the function once per computer with the computer name. This function is then reusable.

Secondly rather than output to a text file, I changed to outputting to a CSV as is a more structured format that can be used better later.

Also rather than relying on writing to the console host, I used `Write-Progress` to report the progress of the loop.

```
$Servers =  Get-Content .\servers.txt
$ExportFileName = "c:\LocalAdminAudit$date.csv"

function Get-LocalAdministrator {
    [cmdletbinding()]  
    Param(
        $ComputerName
    )
    $Group = [ADSI]("WinNT://$computername/Administrators,group")

    try {
        $Group.Invoke("Members") | ForEach-Object {
            $User = ($_.GetType().InvokeMember("Adspath", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) -split '/')[-2,-1] -join '\'
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                "User" = $User
                "Server" = $ComputerName
                "Date" = Get-Date -Format o | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ":", "."}
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "User" = "Failed to Report"
            "Server" = $ComputerName
            "Date" = Get-Date -Format o | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ":", "."}
        }
    }
}

$LocalAdmins = foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    Write-Progress -Activity "Retrieving Local Administrators" -Status "Checking $Server" -PercentComplete (([array]::indexof($Servers,$Server)/($Server.count))*100)
    Get-LocalAdministrator $Server
}

$LocalAdmins | Export-CSV $ExportFileName -NoTypeInformation
Invoke-Item $ExportFileName
```

Lastly, be careful of smart quotes especially when cutting and pasting between Outlook and word.